# How to append a string after a declared string?

Tags: java

A beginner is asking this question so it might sound very basic!....I am still learning how to walk....1 day I will be running :)

I want to amend the following code so that I can insert the word "Great" after the inputted name. The names length varies therefore I know that I have to change line `z.insert(5, " The Great ");`.

Can you please instruct the correct method?

Regards,

```
    Scanner id = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name = " ";
    String surname = " ";

    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
    name = id.nextLine();

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Please enter your surname: ");
    surname = id.nextLine();

    StringBuffer z = new StringBuffer();
    z.append(name + " " + surname + " Is The King of Kings");
    z.insert(5, " The Great ");

    System.out.println(z);
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do something like z.append(name).append(" The Great ")... Or some such?

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate the length of `name`, something like ...

```
int len = name.length() + surname.length() + 1;
```

Should give you the index point after which you can insert the additional String

Personally, it would be better to append the elements in a single step if you can, for example

```
z.append(name).
    append(" ").
    append(surname).
    append(" The Great ").
    apoend("is the King of Kings");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 z.insert(name.length(), " The Great ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a StringBuffer, why not just do a simple String object?

```
String output = name + " The Great " + surname + " Is The King of Kings";
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just the simpler way:

```
StringBuffer z = new StringBuffer();
z.append(name + " The Great " + surname + " Is The King of Kings");
```

This unfortunately doesn't take advantage of `StringBuffer` - to use `StringBuffer` what it's meant for, try

```
z.append(name).append(" The Great ").append(surname).append(" Is The King of Kings");
```

The reason we do it this way is because concatenating Strings using the `+` operator creates a new String object every time we do a concatenation (and throws away the two previous operands). This can create a lot of work for the GC.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `StringBuilder` and some *chained calls*:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(name).append(" The Great ").append(surname).append(" Is the King of Kings");

System.out.println(sb);
```